# Which Cardio machine is best for speed fat burn process?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, training

I want to know which is best for speed fat burn process.

1. Treadmill
2. Stair mill
3. Rowing Machine
4. Airdyne
5. Spin Bike
6. Jacob's Ladder
7. Skierg
8. ARC Trainer
9. Elliptical
   10.Recumbent Bike

Please explain it?

Comment: I don’t think you really understand the fat burn process. I got super lean with a herniated disc in my neck by doing HIIT sessions on a recumbent bike. Others spend their whole life like rats in a wheel on the treadmill and get nothing out of it. It’s how you apply the exercise to your diet and lifestyle. I could lose as much or little as desired (within reason) on any one of those machines. Stop making this complicated, get some discipline, and start crushing your workouts. Fat gone.

Comment: There is no machine that burns fat faster than others. It all depends on how you use them.

Comment: I saw some sites mentioned comparison between each other.

Comment: Look... 20 min on an elliptical with your heart rate at 145 bpm isn’t really any different from a Ski Erg with your heart rate at 145 bpm for 20 min. Some of these machines make it easier to get your heart rate up higher. There might be subtle differences, but the Ski Erg You and the Treadmill You would not look much different. Again, your understanding of how to burn fat seems mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, abs are made in the kitchen, not the gym.  You will never burn off a bad diet, not even if you do nothing else but eat & exercise.

Second, the one that will burn the most fat is the one that you will use the most.  If you enjoy one, use that.

Third, there are a few things that might interfere with frequent usage.  Treadmills for instance have less impact on the knees than running, but are not zero impact.  You simply can't use a treadmill for hours at a time every day the way that you can a bike.  Your knees will explode.  And I say this as a runner.

Eat well, find what you enjoy, and do that.

Comment: "Abs are revealed in the kitchen" would be more accurate. After all, if you never train your abs you'll have a really hard time getting them to show even at a lower BF%.